# How have I paid 7 lots of APD (Air Passenger Duty) for five passengers?

Tags: air-travel, taxes, easyjet

This summer, my wife, three kids (all under 12) and I all flew with EasyJet from Gatwick to Paris CDG, and then from Nice back to Gatwick a week later. Whilst looking at my receipt, I noticed the following line item which confused me:

```
Product              Qty  Unit        Price
Aviation Taxes (APD) 7    per booking 93.25 GBP
```

How have we paid 7 lots of APD? If (as I understand) children under 16 are exempt then I would have expected to either pay two lots or four lots (not sure if it's payable in both directions).

Comment: Guess, based purely on the numbers: Adults pay full fare, kids half. That would make 3.5 units per direction, a total of 7 for a round trip.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta No, kids are definitely exempt from my research. I think I have an answer and am typing it up now.

Comment: That makes sense. +1. In my defense, kids paying half price is not far from them only paying for one of the directions. :)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Defence accepted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the French system has its own version of APD, and in France it's only those under two years old that are exempt ([source](http://www.fccaviation.com/regulation/france/airport-tax)).

So I've paid two lots on the outgoing flight (me and my wife), and five lots on the return flight. What I'm not currently clear about is if I only paid the French portion because it was a different flight, or would it have still been payable if we'd returned from CDG (I think not based on a more recent flight to Spain where it was just me and I only paid one lot).

Comment: Excellent sleuthing. Please ensure you return in a day or two to accept your own answer.